# Get the multiple query ? parameters passed in laravel url

Tags: php, laravel-5

AM using angular4 with laravel and am trying to append query parameters and read them in laravel as follows
My http request is get

The url after adding parameters look like

```
http://localhost:8000/user-management/users?global_filter=12 
 ?paginator=10?page=0?sortfield=username|asc
```

Now in my laravel routes i have

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'user-management','middleware'=>['auth:api']], function() {
    Route::resource('users', "UsersController");
});
```

Now in my usersController i have

```
class UsersController extends Controller{

   public function index(Request $request)
     { 
       return $request->all();
    }
```

Now the above returns

```
global_filter:"null?paginator=10?page=0..."
```

The problem comes when i want to access the paginator value which is null as above.

How do i go about this so that i can be able to retrieve attached values of globalfilter, paginator and sortfield.
I still would wish to continue using the route resource

Comment: Only one `?` allowed in your url, other parameters are separated by `&`

Comment: thanks it now works

Comment: there is a missed part in yours question, how do you create `http://localhost:8000/user-management/users?global_filter=12 
 ?paginator=10?page=0?sortfield=username|asc` ?  please add it's snippet to the question. the problem is because of two ? sign,

Comment: @zhilevan i just attach ? after a variable and the add = value

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI I cant help you with this. pelase provide the part which this url `http://localhost:8000/user-management/users?global_filter=12 
 ?paginator=10?page=0?sortfield=username|asc` is generated.

Comment: @zhilevan the kerbholz suggestion above works. Thanks

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI it was clear your problem is because of double `?` but I'm looking for the reason. by the way, I provide an answer for future guys come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Url in your question `http://localhost:8000/user-management/users?global_filter=12?paginator=10?page=0sortfield=username|ascz`  it seems you wrongly add `?` twice and it caouse the first queryString eliminated and just second part detected, I suggest you use `&` instead of the second `?`.